# MarketingCloudSDK iOS 7.0.1: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I've got an error while archiving my app on Xcode since I updated the Marketing cloud iOS SDK to the lastest version (7.0.1 using CocoaPods)

Error encountered : " **Undefined symbols for architecture armv7** "

I have already checked my project architectures build settings and have included the "armv7"

Can someone help me about that ?

Thank you in advance,

John

Project architecture build settings:

[image]

Error logs:

[image]

Comment: I am also having this issue.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; remove `armv7` from your list of architectures:
[image: target build setting]

SFMC has an iOS minimum of iOS 10 and iirc devices that can run iOS 10 all use newer architectures so it's safe to remove(?)

but standard iOS architecture includes `armv7`

so an official answer would be nice.

linking an issue here: [Supporting armv7 architecture](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297286/supporting-armv7-architecture?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This is the correct response. Our minimum iOS target is now iOS10, and all iOS10 devices support armv7s or arm64. armv7 needs to be removed as a build target.